# VueJS: input with dynamic value + v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with VueJS when setting the value of an input radio AND v-model. I cant understand why I can not setting dynamically a value to an input and use a model to retrive what input the user selected.

In code is easier to understand:

```js
export default {
  props: ["question", "currentQuestion"],

  data() {
    return {
      answer: undefined
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isCurrent() {
      return this.currentQuestion && this.currentQuestion.id == this.question.id;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    groupName(question) {
      return 'question_id_' + question.id
    },
    inputType(question) {
      if (question.question_type_id == 2) return "checkbox";
      return "radio";
     }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  }
    }
```

```html
<template>
    <ul v-if="question.question_type_id != 4">
       <li v-for="option in question.options" :key="option.id">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>
              <input v-model="answer" :value="option.id" :type="inputType(question)" 
    :name="groupName(question)" />
           {{option.option}}
           </label>
         </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

So, in case there are 4 options, the user would see 4 radio buttons, each one with the "option.id" as a value and, WHEN the user clicks the radio button, the model "answer" would be populated with that value.

Now, when I try to compile this file, I get this error message:

> - :value="option.id" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

So, could anyone help me understand how do I dynamically set a value to an input AND asssociate a model to retrieve the value when the input is selected?

By the way, VueJS documentation at this page says exactly what I am trying to do:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

[image: v-model with v-bind:value in the same input]

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue here is that you have a dynamic type on the input element, so I expect Vue is getting a little confused. `value` is not valid in combination with `v-model` for a checkbox input, unless you are binding to an array.

You can solve that by using a v-if/v-else.

```
<label>
  <input v-if="question.question_type_id == 2" 
         v-model="answer" 
         type="checkbox" 
         :name="groupName(question)" />
  <input v-else 
         v-model="answer" 
         :value="option.id" 
         type="radio" 
         :name="groupName(question)" />
  {{option.option}}
</label>
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ypoqJL?editors=1010).

There are other issues, but this addresses the error you mention in the question. For one, it doesn't make much sense for more than one checkbox to be bound to a single `v-model`, unless you are binding to an array. In that case, you would have to swap what type `answer` is based on whether is a radio, a checkbox with a single value or a checkbox with multiple values. Seems like it would get complicated.

Answer (score 4):

the proper way is to use placeholder.

```
<input :placeholder="option.id" v-model="answer" @input="functionToChangeValue($event)"/>
```

! DO NOT USE VALUE AND V-MODEL TOGETHER
it is because v-model create two way biding and your code brake

Comment: this is usefull